# fastest way to get a six pack is it training or is it diet what is the best way to achieve it?

Tags: bodybuilding

i have trained pretty hard for about a year now. i ride a pushbike around 3 times a week i train each muscle group in the gym and go about 4 times a week. i eat reasonably healthy. i have 12 weeks till my wedding. what is the fastest way to get a 6 pack?

Comment: What is your current approximate bodyfat percentage? Use calipers, a scale, or this chart - https://i.imgur.com/xAyq8D4.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Nutrition reveals abs while exercise builds abs.

A six pack is the result of your abdominal muscles being well built enough to be seen at a certain bodyfat percentage and lower. Abs are usually first seen in the 10-15% bodyfat range by the vast majority of people, but can be seen in 20+% range if the abs are particularly well built.

The first thing to keep in mind is how strong are your abs and how much have they been trained. If you aren't/haven't been doing daily ab training then you likely aren't going to have much to work with, but if you have then you should have a good set of abs to work with. The second thing to keep in mind is your current bodyfat percentage. It doesn't matter how big your abs are, they can always be covered up with enough fat. Therefore you need to lose that fat in order to reveal your abs. Losing 1-2% of your total body weight each week is generally a feasible and quick range, and at 1% most of that should be fat.

I should mention a very important disclaimer though, and that is how not everyone is capable of building a six pack. As far as I'm aware, all humans have abs, but not everyone has a potential six pack. Why? What am I talking about? Genetics. Six packs seem to be the most common variation, but some people have four packs and others have eight packs. Arnold Schwarzenegger is a popular example of a guy with a four pack. [This video](https://youtu.be/MDRFqrHCGbs?t=523) looks at that in more detail.

**So what is the fastest way to *SEE* a six pack?** Nutrition, you can lose fat much faster than you could ever hope to build muscle. However, you can be under 10% bodyfat and still not have visible abs so exercise is also very important. The following are some tips that I would suggest.

- Start doing daily ab training, or do five days a week at minimum. "Six Pack Promise" is a free app (limited, full version is paid) that offers a great workout for your entire core in 4-7 minute sessions.
- Eat at a slight caloric deficit, [calculate your TDEE here](https://tdeecalculator.net/) and eat 300-500 calories less than that. Start/keep using a free app called "MyFitnessPal" and make sure to track/plan EVERYTHING that you put in your mouth.
- Continue doing strength training, building additional muscle will keep your metabolism going strong. Doing cardio will also help to keep your metabolism active as long as you're eating enough overall (see TDEE).
- Start supplementing with Creatine, this will help your muscles to look slightly more full (including your abs). Creatine also has many other benefits.

Comment: thanks mate great info. ill let you know how i go